# Running 'syncdb' on heroku for my Django app throws an error

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to create a Django app on Heroku, as detailed by the Heroku/Django Cedar stack tutorial.

I've gotten to the point where I deploy my code on Heroku, but when I run `heroku run python appname/manage.py syncdb`, I get the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "planamo/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 308, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 177, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I don't know what the problem is. What's going on?

Comment: Answered my own question: you have to run `heroku addons:add shared-database`

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it, so this question appears as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question: you have to run `heroku addons:add shared-database`

Comment: this may be obsolete with the shared databases becoming obsolete (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres)

Answer (score 2):

I just found another cause for this error. Heroku injects code at the end of settings.py file.

**If last line of settings.py don't contains a carry return injected code may be ignored**.

This is the case of [django-social-auth's settings.py file](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/example/settings.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add: 'HOST': '127.0.0.1' in your database config in settings.py